# When to use a TypeScript primitive's interface

Tags: typescript, types

Came across a question regarding type interfaces that I cannot understand (unless it's incorrect)

`methodName(): <Map<String, String>> {...`

**Is this return type incorrect and or perhaps meant to be `<string, string>`?**

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, no, we know what the difference is but the case above is not how I would ever use a primitive's interface. I'd only use `String` when extending the type into a new interface. Never as a return type.

Comment: Then please [edit] to clarify what you _are_ asking. Maybe you could include _where_ you came across that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only legitimate case I can think of that you are using the `String` constructor (for some reason), and you therefore run into the fact that `String` is not assignable to `string`.

```
const str: string = new String('testing123')
// Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'string'.
//   'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object.
//     Prefer using 'string' when possible.(2322)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOAuOV4EswHMYF4ZgFMB3GAZVQ0wAoByKA6SgRgCYBmGgSiA)

All all likelihood, however, this is a mistake. If you change those to `string` and everything still type checks fine, then it was almost certainly a mistake.

Comment: for the win! Thanks.